# For connecting convolutional layers with final dense layers, when is global pooling preferred over flattening and vice versa?

Tags: conv-neural-network

Flattening preserves all the input values although it loses the 2D spatial connectivity.

Global pooling condenses the 2D matrix from each activation map into a single value so it is very lossy.

When designing CNN architectures, is there a rule of thumb about when should each method be used when connecting convolutional layers to dense layers?

Comment: Nowadays, it's common to use 1x1 convolution for flattening

Comment: Thanks. 1x1 convolution is the third option.  I am interested in the pros and cons for each of these options.